# What is this usage of がいい_

Tags: adjectives, reading-comprehension

> 誰も傷つけずに生きてくことなんてできないだろ
> ...だったら
> お前がいい
> 自分の中に残るものは全部お前がいい
> お前がどうしたい?

I understand the first sentence is akin to "It's impossible to live without hurting" followed by then "If that's the case, you are fine."

Then the final sentence is akin to "自分の中に残るものは全部" "all that is left inside of me now, is..."

How is お前がいい being used here?

Comment: It is *to prefer*, as you probably already understand. You are not providing enough contexts to make sense of the quotes. Related [What is the difference between のちがいい and あとがいい？](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/49118)

Comment: Who is saying which line? What is the relationship between the speaker and the listener (お前) like?

Comment: All the lines are spoken by the same person. They are speaking to the person they are in love with.

Answer (score 1):

That part doesn't translate very cleanly into English, so I get why you're confused. Check out the explanation of ~がいい in the thread sundowner linked to; it says that it's used to express a preference, and in this case the speaker is effectively just repeating that he likes the お前 person -- almost like he's saying "you're the one [for me]". I'd translate this as something like

> You can't live life without hurting anyone /
> ...so,
> / You're the one [for me].
> / Everything left inside me wants (/prefers/likes) you. [see naruto's comment below]
> / What do *you* want to do?

This is sort of an impressionistic translation, but hopefully it helps.

Comment: +1, but the 4th line is "I hope you will be the only thing left inside me" rather than "everything left inside me wants you".

Comment: @naruto: ah, you're right, duh! good catch