# あなたはそれでよいのです what/how does the でよい bit here work?

Tags: translation, nuances

Context: Jobs are being appointed and one of the minions is given a simple job of wrecking some place. The minion exclaims how simple it is (not the smartest cookie) and then the job giver (the strategist minion) says:

> あなたはそれでよいのです

I'm not excatly sure about the meaning here of the それでよい bit.

I'm assuming that で here is in it's cause and effect use. Like "If that (is done/is simple for you) then it's good/well/okay". I'm not sure if it's being said that:

1. "It will be fine if you do that"
2. "You'll do good/perform excellently if you do that"
3. "It's good that it's simple for you/that you understand".
4. something else?

PS: More context:

> Minion 1: LeaderさまLeaderさま, 結局ボクは何すればいいの？
>
> Minion 2 (the strategist): Minion 1はあの辺りを掘り返して Leaderを悪く言う相手を叩きのめせばよいのですよ
>
> Minion 1: シンプル！
>
> Minion 2: あなたはそれでよいのです

Comment: Do you have the exact Japanese conversation?

Comment: You are asking about それ without sharing the original previous context... That's not good...

Comment: I mean, there isn't much more than I mention in the first sentence. It's basically: Minion 1: What should I do? Minion 2: Go wrekc shit over there. Minion 1: Sweet! Minion 2: Do that! <the bit I don't completelly get.

Comment: Doesn't direct translation "You are fine with that" make sense?

Comment: So basically they are saying if that job is done the minion has done their thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- For this で, please read: [What is the difference between それでいい and それがいい here?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17851/5010)
- This それ simply refers to his simple task (あのあたりを掘り返して...).

So this それでよい implies "That's all I expect about you", or "If you can do this (simple) task, that's already enough to me". The leader is implying there are more important tasks, but they are not suitable for this minion.