# What is the meaning of いいから in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

I struggle a lot to understand this sentence :

願い叶うのならひと目で**いいから**

I can't find any coherence with the first part of the sentence.

Comment: [Direct translations are off-topic](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/799/5010) unless your current effort is clearly indicated. Can we assume you already know what ひと目 and でいい mean? And is this from Taeyeon's song *Voice*?

Comment: I don' ask for a translation. If you have recognized Taeyeon lyrics you should know that it is not difficult to have an english translation (Forひと目or other nouns and verbs). But, as a beginner, I would like to understand how it is possible that the end of the sentence with いいからcan be translated by "it is good at first sight".(If いい is good how からis translated ?
PS. I ask that because I have seen that on this site question for the meaning of nouns or adverbs in different grammatical situation are countless. Maybe I haven't understand that this site is not for beginner, sorry

Comment: We want your translation attempt because that clearly indicates your point of confusion. "It is good at first sight" is actually a terrible translation, but it at least shows we have to explain to you the true meaning of this ひと目 and the meaning of でいい.

Comment: Please also note that beginner questions are more than welcome here. But no one can tell whether you are a beginner or an expert if you don't try to explain what you already know about this line.

Answer (score 4):

> 願い叶うのならひと目でいいから
>   If someone makes my wish come true, only a single glance will do, so (please let me see you!)

- ひと目 is "glance" or "seeing for a very short time" rather than "first sight".
- ～でいい is a construction to express your minimal desire. "(something) is not ideal but acceptable" or "～ will at least do". See: [What is the difference between それでいい and それがいい here?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17851/5010)
- から is a reason marker. I translated it as "so" here. から is usually followed by a result/conclusion part, but it's omitted in this case. Although her wish is not directly mentioned, it is self-evident if we have access to the [full lyrics](https://genius.com/Taeyeon-voice-lyrics). She wants to see the person she loves, and that's her 願い ("wish") here.