# だが同じ本を読むことでも、同じ本を話すでもいいからやってみたほうがいい。

Tags: meaning

だが同じ本を読むことでも、同じ本を話すでもいいからやってみたほうがいい。

Does anyone know what the いいから means here?
My guess:
"But, the same book to be read, the same book to be talked about is good to try?"
What would the difference be if I took out いいから and just said:
だが同じ本を読むことでも、同じ本を話すでもやってみたほうがいい。

Would the meaning change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sentence has the `～で(も)いい` construction to express something is fine/acceptable (if not ideal).

- [What is the difference between それでいい and それがいい here?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17851/5010)
- Maggie Sensei: [Noun + で(も）いい　VS +がいい ( = Noun + de (mo) ii vs + ga ii)](https://maggiesensei.com/2014/05/20/%e3%80%9c%e3%81%a7%e3%81%84%e3%81%84-%e3%80%9c%e3%81%a7%e3%82%82%e3%81%84%e3%81%84%e3%80%80vs%e3%80%80%e3%80%9c%e3%81%8c%e3%81%84%e3%81%84-de-ii-demo-ii-vs-ga-ii/)

This sentence has two でも, meaning whichever is fine.

- XでもYでもいい
  = XでもいいしYでもいい
  X is fine and Y is fine, too
  X or Y, whichever is fine
- 同じ本を読むことでも、同じ本を話す(こと)でもいい
  reading the same book is fine, and talking about the same book is fine, too
- 同じ本を読むことでも、同じ本を話す(こと)でもいいからやってみたほうがいい。
  Reading the same book or talking about the same book, you should do whichever you like (together with your girlfriend).